# First VerticalViewPager page blank

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have a problem that relates to Android's ViewPager. I am attempting to implement a VerticalViewPager (though that is not relevant to the problem as this same problem occurs with a normal ViewPager) with a custom PagerAdapter that gets data from my database and inputs it onto the screen.

The problem is that my first card appears to be blank until I slide it over to the next page and come back. After that the content is there. I'm not exactly sure what was going on so hopefully someone can shed some light on this issue. I found a similar problem here: Why is the first view in ViewPager appearing empty? and Activity using ViewPager, PagerAdapter and AsyncTask causes a blank view but it seems as if nothing in there is able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify that the page has been set by the adapter. Just addthis line after you set the adapter:

```
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When you come back next time, your page is invalidated by fragment callbacks.

Comment: That didn't work, I'm using a cursor loader to send the data to each of my ViewPager views. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

https://github.com/BABACHAN/VerticalViewPager

I stuck with same problem until I found it. Works perfectly, you can see the code and find solution for yourself.